# Where Clause OverRides Max()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am executing this query but it returns more than just the Max() id when I throw in the where clause.  Is there a way to still only return the max() even with this where clause?

```
Select ID, Max(saledate), empName, saleStatusCode
From saleDatabase
Where saleStatusCode In (1, 3, 8, 12, 14, 22)
Group By ID, empName, saleStatusCode
Order By ID Asc
```

Sorry for my non clarity guys...here is some sample data

```
Create Table #Test
(
  ID int,
  saledate datetime,
  empName varchar(500),
  saleStatusCode int
(

INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES (1, '12/12/2014', 'Joe Joe Joe', 2)
INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES (1, '12/07/2014', 'Mitchell', 2)
INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES (1, '12/10/3014', 'Mark', 1)

Select id, Max(saledate), empName, saleStatusCode
FROM #Test
Where salestatuscode IN (1, 2, 3, 8, 122, 14, 22)
Group by id, empname, salestatuscode
Order By id asc
```

Now if you run that, each entry is returned?  What I need returned would be the ID with the max(saledate) so I would want only the 1st record returned.

Comment: What do you mean the where clause overrides `max()`? Can you post some sample data and then the result that the query gives?  Then show the expected output.

Comment: What do you mean by "more than the max"? The second field will display the highest `saledate` per each combination of `ID, empName, saleStatusCode`. Do you want the max of the whole table on each row instead? Please add some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: @Andrew - my code above has multiple id's returning, working on posting sample data as requested by bluefeet

Comment: Of course, if you `Group By ID, empName, saleStatusCode`, you will get one row per each combination of those values in your source table. If you want the maximum value of the entire table, you should not do any grouping.

Comment: @MasterOfStupidQuestions, please not that your table creation code ends with `(`, and that Mark's date is 3014. And also I guess the `ID` values should not all be `1`.

Comment: @Andrew that was a typo omission for the closing paren, and I do want all of them to have an ID of 1 as in this instance the table structure is beyond horrid so I was needing a way to get the max id when there are multiple instances of the same id in the same table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that your requirements are clear, I think this is what you need:

```
SELECT ID, saledate, empName, saleStatusCode
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY saledate DESC) RowOrder, *
    FROM #Test
    ) SUBQ
WHERE RowOrder = 1
```

In your case, the result is:

```
1   2014-12-12 00:00:00.000 Joe Joe Joe 2
```

Actually the result would show Mark, because its date is from 3014, but I guess that was a typo. ;)

**Important edit:**

Oh, John H's comment made me rethink this and I found out that I was totally overthinking your problem!! Your request could have been solved as easily as this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM #Test
WHERE saleStatusCodeIN (1, 2, 3, 8, 122, 14, 22)
ORDER BY saledate DESC
```

How could I have missed that?

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE` clause is evaluated before the `GROUP BY` and before any aggregate functions by design.  To filter after the aggregate, use the `HAVING` clause:

```
Select ID, Max(saledate), empName, saleStatusCode
From saleDatabase
Group By ID, empName, saleStatusCode
Having saleStatusCode In (1, 3, 8, 12, 14, 22)
Order By ID Asc
```

Or use a subquery:

```
Select a.ID, a.Max_saledate, a.empName, a.saleStatusCode
From (
    Select ID, Max(saledate) "Max_saledate", empName, saleStatusCode
    From saleDatabase
    Group By ID, empName, saleStatusCode) a
Where saleStatusCode In (1, 3, 8, 12, 14, 22) 
Order By ID Asc
```

Comment: Anyway in this case I think having that condition in the `WHERE` or the `HAVING` will give the exact same result. There's no difference in the `saleStatusCode` after the grouping.

Comment: @Andrew Yeah, you're right.  I was thinking the conditional was a different field entirely, but it isn't.

Answer (score -2):

You question is not clear. You only whant the MAX value from saleDate? then try this:

```
Select Max(saledate)
From saleDatabase
Where saleStatusCode In (1, 3, 8, 12, 14, 22)
```